# GitLab CI: how to return command stdout to the code where it was called?

Tags: notifications, gitlab-ci, stdout, rc

I have this piece of code in the yaml file:

```
.setUpEnvironment:
  stage: provision
  script:
    - |
      cd ansible
      ansible-playbook install_app.yml <...>
      <... n more lines here>
      echo 'rc = ' $(install_app.rc)
      echo 'stdout = ' $(install_app.stdout)
  allow_failure: true
```

I need to send notification if the script fails. The problem is that neither install_app.rc nor install_app.stdout works for me. There is 'bash: line 217: install_app_win.rc: command not found
rc =
bash: line 218: install_app_win.stdout: command not found' Do you have any ideas how to fix this behavior?

Thanks in advance,
Irina

Comment: Hi that_startup_girl welcome to SO. That posted yaml sure does look like GitLab CI, and not ansible; are you sure you have tagged your question correctly? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @mdaniel, I'll fix the tag